# Showing second-countable + T$_1$ + compact implies sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a second-countable T$_1$-space. If $X$ is compact then it is sequentially compact.

I know that compact implies countably compact. And under the condition that $X$ is first-countable: countably compact implies sequentially compact. Since $X$ is second-countable, thus first-countable, we have that $X$ is sequentially compact.

Is this correct? As the conditions of $X$ being a second-countable T$_1$-space weren't *really* used here, I suspect something is wrong.

However, those conditions may be needed to show that if $X$ is sequentially compact then it is compact.

Comment: As Brian showed we just need a first countable compact space $X$ to conclude that $X$ is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, and if one goes into a bit more detail, it is possible to eliminate the $T_1$ hypothesis.

Suppose that $X$ is compact and first countable, and let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $X$. Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. If $A$ is finite, $\sigma$ has a constant subsequence, which of course converges to a point of $X$. Otherwise, compactness of $X$ implies that the set $A$ has a limit point $p$.

> We do not need $X$ to be $T_1$ for this to hold. If $A$ has no limit point, then each $x\in X$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap A$ is finite. $\{U_x:x\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq X$ such that $\{U_x:x\in F\}$ covers $X$. But then $A=\bigcup\{U_x\cap A:x\in F\}$ is a finite union of finite sets and so is finite, contrary to our assumption.

Now let $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable local base at $p$; without loss of generality we may assume that $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. (Why?) There is an $m_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_{m_0}\in B_0$. Given $m_k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, there is an $m_{k+1}\in\Bbb N$ such that $m_k<m_{k+1}$ and $x_{m_{k+1}}\in B_{k+1}$, since $B_{k+1}\cap A$ is infinite. In this way we can recursively construct a subsequence $\langle x_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of $\sigma$ such that $x_{m_k}\in B_\ell$ for all $k\ge \ell$, and clearly this subsequence converges to $p$. This shows that $X$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: @D.Math: I don’t see any way to do so, since this result actually assumes compactness. To show that a countably compact metric space is compact I would probably first show that it’s limit point compact, then use that to show that it’s totally bounded, then use that to show that it’s separable, then use that to show that it’s second countable; that immediately implies that it’s Lindelöf, and a Lindelöf, countably compact space is compact.